# Url rewriting htaccess specific word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this

```
RewriteRule ^article/?$ articles.php [L]
```

Currently this works both of them for these url : articles?id=100 and articles?id=100/Manage

But I would like to **exclude a specific word** : Manage after articles?id=100

This url will be forbidden : articles?id=100/manage

But articles?id=100 is OK

How can I change this ?

I try

```
RewriteRule ^article/?$/^(Manage) articles.php [L]
#or
RewriteRule ^article/?$/(Manage) articles.php [L,R=404]
```

But It doesn't work.
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This involves more than just .htaccess file. 
Your need a php function to work alone with the .htaccess

```
function slug($string, $spaceRepl = "-") {

  // Replace "&" char with "and"

  $string = str_replace("&", "and", $string);

  // Delete any chars but letters, numbers, spaces and _, -

  $string = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/", "", $string);

  // Optional: Make the string lowercase

  $string = strtolower($string);

  // Optional: Delete double spaces

  $string = preg_replace("/[ ]+/", " ", $string);

  // Replace spaces with replacement

  $string = str_replace(" ", $spaceRepl, $string);

  return $string;

}

?>
```

and your htaccess
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) articles.php?id=$1
```

Follow this tutorial http://www.simplecss3.com/tutorial/19/how-to-make-a-seo-friendly-url-using-php-and-htaccess